# What's needed to support non-square matrices in GLSL shader?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, shader, gpu

I'm trying to use non-square matrices in my GLSL shader but when I compile I get a syntax error.

My shader code using:

```
uniform mat4 my_mat;
```

compiles just fine.

But if I change it to:

```
uniform mat4x3 my_mat;
```

I get

```
ERROR: 0:5: 'mat4x3' : syntax error syntax error
```

I get a similar error for

```
uniform mat4x4 my_mat;
```

If I print my GL_VERSION and GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION I get:
GL_VERSION: 2.1 NVIDIA-1.6.36
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: 1.20

I'm compiling and running my OpenGL on a Mac OS X 10.6 MacBook Pro. According to [this NVidia document](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/glsl/glsl_release_notes.pdf) and others, GLSL 1.20 and GL 2.1 should encompass support of non-square matrices and this syntax. Is there another catch? Or another way to troubleshoot why I get syntax errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I place

```
#version 120
```

At the top of my shader code, the problem goes away. According to [the same document listed in the question](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/glsl/glsl_release_notes.pdf) shader source without the version compiler option will compile "as before" which I guess means that they won't.

Comment: That is exactly what you need to do. Without a version specification the shader is compiled as 1.10. I guess you see that just trying this out before asking the question would have been a good idea, as you obviously tryed it out some minutes after asking the question. But nevermind now you got a nice question with a self-accepted answer.

Comment: With no `#version` it should compile it as if it was `#version 110`, as that was the last version where `#version` was optional.